# How to append a string into a list in parallel with a dictionary

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary, file-io

I am importing a text file that relates planets to their status as either True - for planet, or False - for dwarf, that has to be in the same order as the dictionaries keys are below.

Here is the dictionary named "sol":

{'Uranus': [2750, 3000, 2880], 'Mercury': [46, 70, 57], 'Earth': [147, 152, 150], 'Venus': [107, 109, 108], 'Mars': [205, 249, 228], 'Saturn': [1350, 1510, 1430], 'Jupiter': [741, 817, 779], 'Neptune': [4450, 4550, 4500], 'Pluto': [4440, 7380, 5910]}

And here is the data file I'm importing named status1.dat:

```
Mars,True
Mercury,True
Neptune,True
Uranus,True
Earth,True
Venus,True
Pluto,False
Jupiter,True
Saturn,True
```

So with the below code, I was told to not use CSV just use standard loops, My logic has me opening the data file. Splitting the lines down so I can match the planet name "li[0]", with sol[key]. If they do match, then append the status "li[1]" to the end of the list. Of course, this is going in the order of the data file and not the dictionaries keys. Is there a way to alter the below code to have the status fall in line with the keys? Or do I have to put the dictionary key loop first?

```
status =[]

def load_status(sol, status):
    with open(status1.dat, "r") as s:
        for line in s:
            line = line.rstrip('\n')
            if len(line) > 0:
                li = line.split(',')
                for key in sol:
                    if key == li[0]:
                        status.append(li[1])
        print(status)
```

Print(status) as of now gives in the order of the data file as shown below right now:

['True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'False', 'True', 'True']

Correct order would be for the list:

['True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'False']

Comment: You don't need to worry about the order of the dict. Just index into it with `sol[key]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minimizing changes to your code

```
def load_status(sol):

  with open('status1.dat', "r") as s:
      for line in s:
          line = line.rstrip('\n')
          if len(line) > 0:
              k, v = line.split(',')  # get key, value from line
              if k in sol:            # if key in dictionary
                sol[k].append(v)      # append value to did entry

      # Create status (looping in same order as keys)
      # based upon last item in list i.e. v[-1]
      status = [v[-1] for k, v in sol.items()] 

      return sol, status
```

**Test**

```
new_sol, status = load_stats(sol)

print(status)

from pprint import pprint
pprint(new_sol)                       # pretty print dictionary
```

**Output**

```
['True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'False']

{'Earth': [147, 152, 150, 'True'],
 'Jupiter': [741, 817, 779, 'True'],
 'Mars': [205, 249, 228, 'True'],
 'Mercury': [46, 70, 57, 'True'],
 'Neptune': [4450, 4550, 4500, 'True'],
 'Pluto': [4440, 7380, 5910, 'False'],
 'Saturn': [1350, 1510, 1430, 'True'],
 'Uranus': [2750, 3000, 2880, 'True'],
 'Venus': [107, 109, 108, 'True']}
```

**Addendum**

Create status without modifying sol

```
def load_status(sol):

  with open('status1.dat', "r") as s:
      # create a lookup table for each sol key
      sol_key_index = {k:i for i, k in enumerate(sol.keys())}
      # Make status array the size of the keys
      status = [0] * len(sol.keys())
      for line in s:
          line = line.rstrip('\n')
          if len(line) > 0:
              k, v = line.split(',')             # get key, value from line
              if k in sol:                       # if key in dictionary
                status[sol_key_index[k]] = v     # append value to status

      return status
```

*Usage*

```
status = load_status(sol)
```

*Output*

```
['True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'False']
```

Comment: Thanks Darryl, However, I need a separate list called status with them in that order to allow other functions to work. This list will me manipulated once in the correct order and then there will be changes to the dictionary.

Comment: @JasonMcKinnerney--is the order based upon the order in the file?

Comment: @JasonMcKinnerney--see update.  Function returns status which is based upon the order in the file.

Comment: the order is based on the order of the planets from a file that has the information that created the dictionary sol, so the same order as the dictionary keys at the top shows.

Comment: @JasonMcKinnerney--okay, updated solution to have that order.

Comment: thanks man for your help. I did need to remove the added value from the dictionary for the time being. I used for k, v in listDict.items():
    v.pop()

Comment: @JasonMcKinnerney--yes that should work. Alternatively, if you don't want the value you can update status without updating sol.  Do you see how the code would change to do that?

Comment: @ Darryl, I dont. I tried adjusting it over the last 2 hours to do that, but I couldn't figure it out. It seemed the way it was structured that the list wouldn't populate if the values weren't in the dictionary.

Comment: @JasonMcKinnerney--I added an addendum that creates status without modifying sol.  Trickier than I thought.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desire order by parsing first the file to a dict and then iterate over the sol keys and check there value in the parsed dict.

```
def load_status(sol):
    with open(status1.dat, "r") as s:
        stat_dc = {i.split(",")[0]: i.split(",")[1] for i in s.split("\n")
        status = [stat_dc[i] for i in sol]
        print(status)
```

Output

```
['True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'True', 'False']
```